# How can I sort List[Int] objects?

Tags: scala, sorting, scala-2.9

What I want to do is sort List objects in Scala, not sort the elements in the list. For example If I have two lists of Ints:

```
val l1 = List(1, 2, 3, 7)
val l2 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 10)
```

I want to be able to put them in order where l1 > l2.

I have created a case class that does what I need it to but the problem is that when I use it none of my other methods work. Do I need to implement all the other methods in the class i.e. flatten, sortWith etc.?

My class code looks like this:

```
class ItemSet(itemSet: List[Int]) extends Ordered[ItemSet] {

  val iSet: List[Int] = itemSet

  def compare(that: ItemSet) = {

    val thisSize = this.iSet.size
    val thatSize = that.iSet.size
    val hint = List(thisSize, thatSize).min
    var result = 0
    var loop = 0

    val ths = this.iSet.toArray
    val tht = that.iSet.toArray

    while (loop < hint && result == 0) {
      result = ths(loop).compare(tht(loop))
      loop += 1
    }
    if (loop == hint && result == 0 && thisSize != thatSize) {
      thisSize.compare(thatSize)
    } else
      result
  }

}
```

Now if I create an Array of ItemSets I can sort it:

```
val is1 = new ItemSet(List(1, 2, 5, 8))
val is2 = new ItemSet(List(1, 2, 5, 6))
val is3 = new ItemSet(List(1, 2, 3, 7, 10))

Array(is1, is2, is3).sorted.foreach(i => println(i.iSet))

scala> List(1, 2, 3, 7, 10)
List(1, 2, 5, 6)
List(1, 2, 5, 8)
```

The two methods that are giving me problems are:

```
def itemFrequencies(transDB: Array[ItemSet]): Map[Int, Int] = transDB.flatten.groupBy(x => x).mapValues(_.size)
```

The error I get is:

> Expression of type Map[Nothing, Int] doesn't conform to expected type Map[Int, Int]

And for this one:

```
def sortListAscFreq(transDB: Array[ItemSet], itemFreq: Map[Int, Int]): Array[List[Int]] = {
  for (l <- transDB) yield
    l.sortWith(itemFreq(_) < itemFreq(_))
}
```

I get:

> Cannot resolve symbol sortWith.

Is there a way I can just extend List[Int] so that I can sort a collection of lists without loosing the functionality of other methods?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard library provides [a lexicographic ordering](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering%24%24Implicits%24) for collections of ordered things. You can put it into scope and you're done:

```
scala> import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._

scala> val is1 = List(1, 2, 5, 8)
is1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5, 8)

scala> val is2 = List(1, 2, 5, 6)
is2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 5, 6)

scala> val is3 = List(1, 2, 3, 7, 10)
is3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 7, 10)

scala> Array(is1, is2, is3).sorted foreach println
List(1, 2, 3, 7, 10)
List(1, 2, 5, 6)
List(1, 2, 5, 8)
```

The [`Ordering` type class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering) is often more convenient than `Ordered` in Scala—it allows you to specify how some existing type should be ordered without having to change its code or create a proxy class that extends `Ordered[Whatever]`, which as you've seen can get messy very quickly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe I just spent 2 days trying get everything to work.

Comment: @Val, I guess that's sarcasm but you're kind of missing the point—the _array_ of lists is _not_ sorted before calling `.sorted`, and then it is. Also I'm just using the OP's examples, which is generally a good idea.